# Creating array pointer in main, then allocate memory in some function

Tags: c

I want to define multiple array pointers in my main, and then pass these pointers into a function to allocate memory for them. The thing is that the size of the array is not known before entering `somefunction`. I am not sure how to do this or if there is a better way to do this, but I tried with this code, which did not work.

```
void somefunction(int *arr1,int *arr2){
    int M = 3;
    int N = 2;
    arr1 = (int*)malloc(M*sizeof(int));
    arr2 = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
}

int main(){
    int* array_1;
    int* array_2;
    somefunction(array_1,array_2);
    //Here I want array_1 to be of size M and array_2 of size N
}
```

Comment: When do you definitely know the size of the Arrays ?

Comment: After doing some actions in the start of somefunction. Simplified by setting M=3 and N=2. So after M and N i set, the size is known

Comment: Define `somefunction` as `void somefunction(int **arr1,int **arr2)` and call it from main with `somefunction(&array_1,&array_2)`. Allocate with `*arr1 = (int*)malloc(M*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Will it be safe to set a `temporary_array = (int*)malloc(M*sizeof(int));` inside `void somefunction(int **arr1,int **arr2)` and then set `*arr1 = temporary_array`? Or will `temporary_array` be removed from memory after `somefunction` has been executed?